# Combination of S3 bucket, fuse, rclone mount and incron - not detecting changes

Tags: centos, amazon-s3, fuse

and thanks for reading.....

I'm trying to setup a method whereby I have an on-premise Centos 7 server which uses rclone (mount) to mount an AWS S3 bucket as a file system. I've installed fuse to make this all work fine. When a file is added to the S3 bucket by an external system, it appears as an entry in the filesystem (no surproses there!).

I then want to trigger a script whenever a file is added to the bucket by an external system, so I've setup incron to try and detect directory changes and trigger the script.

The issue I have is that if I add a file to the filesystem from the on-premise Centos 7 box, the incron triggers perfectly. However if an external system writes to the S3 bucket and it's rclone'd mounted to the Centos 7 server, then incron doesn't trigger the script.

My theory, FWIW, is that because an external system is writing the file to the bucket then incron / fuse is not detecting a filesystem change.

Does this make sense ? Is there an alternative that will enable incron to detect the change ? Or should I use rclone to physically copy the files into a local filesystem which should trigger incron I guess.

Any and all contributions are appreciated.

Regards,
D

Comment: This is a well known limitation of FUSE filesystems. You're going to need a different approach for whatever you're doing (which you didn't say anything about).

Comment: Thank you Michael, my suspicions confirmed. I really appreciate your help.